# Pros and cons of async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, readability

In 2013, Microsoft added new feature to the .NET framework to help handling asynchronous tasks: [`async`/`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

How does this feature affect the readability of the code?

Here are few disadvantages that I found:

- It is the same as using return in the middle of the method: it makes it hard to catch the flow of the code.
- It reminds of GOTO in C: it makes it hard to catch the flow of the code.

Comment: You are a way off. It's not a new feature in VS but in .NET framework. VS have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek tnx, changed it

Comment: You can only not appreciate it if you've never written asynchronous code before.  Which forces you keep state in the fields of class instead of local variables.  A state machine is required to track state.  Hard to write, hard to debug, invariably fatal to code readability.  Sure, there are logical returns and gotos underneath.  You don't actually write them, big difference.

Answer (score 11):

`async`/`await` are not easy to understand, but once you get the principle of synchonization context capture/restore, it's relatively easy to follow the code flow.

The main issue with this feature IMO is the *async all the way* problem, i.e. once you're writing an asynchronous piece of code, all your code tends to become asynchronous too.

I recommend this excellent [article on MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for a good understanding of the whole async topic.

Comment: It's true that the "async all the way" does affect the amount of refactoring you have to do. However, once the refactoring is done, you end up with a *much* better solution. :)